# Python Variable not printing

Tags: python

I have a project in my programming class to create something in python and i decided to make a pokedex. but not sure why when i give it the input of 1 when it asks for the pokenumber it returns none.

```
import random
import time

print "Hello new Trainer!"
time.sleep(1.6)
print "I am your Kanto region Pokédex"
time.sleep(2.3)
print "Please enter your name below so I may know what to call you."
time.sleep(2)
name = raw_input("Name:")
time.sleep(1)
print "Hello %s, it is nice to meet you" % (name)
time.sleep(2)
print "I am a Pokédex, a Pokédex is a database of Pokémon."
time.sleep(3)
print "This  Pokédex is specific for Pokémon in the Kanto region."
time.sleep(3.5)
print "All Pokémon have an assigned number that corresponds to that         certain Pokémon species"
time.sleep(4)
print "For example, Pikachu is the 25th entry in the Pokédex!"
time.sleep(3)
print "When you enter a Pokémon's # it will bring up all available    information on that Pokémon"
time.sleep(5)
print "Please enter a number between 1 and 151 to learn about the Pokémon associated to that number."
Bulbasaur = "Bulbasaur can be seen napping in bright sunlight. There is a seed on its back. By soaking up the sun's rays, the seed grows progressively larger."

userpoke = raw_input("Pokémon #:")
def userpoke():
  if userpoke == 1:
    print (Bulbasaur)
```

Comment: You have a variable and a function with the same name !!

Comment: You must have diff function name and must call at last and also you need to  cast `string` to `int` of `raw_input`.

Comment: You are doing so many things wrong here that I'd say you need to review your instructional materials before asking a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues in the last few lines:

```
userpoke = raw_input("Pokémon #:")
```

This reads a string from user input, and save it in variable `userpoke`.

```
def userpoke():
  if userpoke == 1:
    print (Bulbasaur)
```

This overwrites the previously created variable `userpoke`, and replaces it with a function that checks whether its own function object is equal to the integer 1. This function is also never called.

Try the following instead. This uses a different name for the function, so as not to overwrite the previously created variable, converts `userpoke` to an integer before trying to compare it to an integer, and then actually calls the function.

```
userpoke = raw_input("Pokémon #:")

def print_userpoke_details():
  if int(userpoke) == 1:
    print (Bulbasaur)

print_userpoke_details()
```

Even better would be to avoid the use of globals:

```
def print_userpoke_details(userpoke):
  if int(userpoke) == 1:
    print (Bulbasaur)

userpoke = raw_input("Pokémon #:")
print_userpoke_details(userpoke)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) parses what you type as a string. You will need to cast it to an integer using [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int), or you can take the easy road and compare it to the string `"1"` instead of just the integer `1`.

Edit: as a commenter just pointed out, you also have a variable and a function with the same name:

```
userpoke = raw_input("Pokémon #:")
def userpoke():
  if userpoke == 1:
    print (Bulbasaur)
```

In this case, the `userpoke` in your `if` statement actually refers to the function, not the variable. I'd recommend you do something like this:

```
def userpoke():
  pkmn_num = raw_input("Pokémon #:")
  if pkmn_num == "1":
    print (Bulbasaur)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have diff function name. The function name and variable name are same, try following changes:

```
def _userpoke():
  if userpoke == '1':
    print (Bulbasaur)

_userpoke()
```

May be this will help you.